# LaunchScreen.xib toolbar positions BarButtonItems wrongly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, launch

I'm using a LaunchScreen.xib file that shows a UIToolbar with a few BarButtonItems. This toolbar and its items are exactly analogous to an equivalent toolbar in the actual app. Theoretically the use of a LaunchScreen.xib file allows iOS to dynamically position screen elements based on the device itself so that there's no need to make mock-ups and screenshots of interfaces on various devices.

The UIToolbar in my LaunchScreen.xib, however, has the buttons positioned wrongly. Here's the resulting launch screen on an iPhone (left) and the app after it has launched (right).

[image: Image during launch][image: Image immediately after launch]

You can see that the buttons on the outer edge of the first image are touching the sides of the window whereas in the second image they are inset slightly.

How do I make the button positioning on a UIToolbar in a LaunchScreen.xib file match that in a UIToolbar in the main .xib file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 2 constant spacing items to your LaunchScreen toolbar on the left and right side of toolbar

Comment: That worked. Don't know why it's necessary but it's a good workaround. I added fixed space bar button items at 16px wide each.